# Do these two groups contain a $S_3$ as a subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have the following groups 
$$
G_1 = \langle S,T : S^3 = T^2 = (ST)^2 \rangle
$$
$$
G_2 = \langle S,T : S^4 = T^6 = (ST)^2 = (S^{-1}T)^2 = 1\rangle,
$$
which have order $12$ and $24$ respectively.

I am trying to figure out if these groups contain the symmetric group $S_3$ as a subgroup or not. I have been playing around with it, but I couldn't find an easy way to verify. I would appreciate any hint/comments/answers! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$G_1$ looks like the dihedral group to me:

In $D_3$ you have $R^3 = F^2 = (RF)^2 = e$ where $R$ is rotation by $120$ degrees. Now the question boils down to whether $D_3$ contains $S_3$ or not.

Try to show that $S_3$ and $D_3$ are isomorphic.

Regarding $G_2$:

If $T$ has order $6$ then $T^2$ has order 3. Similarly, if $S$ has order $4$ then $S^2$ has order $2$. So, $T^2$ is a candidate to map to 3-cycles and $S^2$ is a candidate for the transpositions in $S_3$.

Comment: Re $G_2$: The element $S^2$ is central so $S^2$ and $T^2$ generate a cyclic group of order $6$. I think $ST$ and $T^2$ generate a copy of $S_3$.

Comment: @ZoeH I stand corrected, thank you for your comment Zoe.